# PUSH уведомления через вэб

Tags: php, push-уведомления

Приветствую!

В вэб проект под php необходимо реализовать подписку через PUSH уведомления.

Вопрос как это сделать, я так понимаю нужно сделать 1. подписку и 2. отправку сообщений всем подписчикам в операционки/браузеры через push сервис.

Интересует пример именнj кодинг!

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/321924/   лень перепечатовать

Comment: На хабре там для андройд только, я думаю onesignal больше подходит так как в windows 10 отсылает. Но я так и не понял, как именно на onesignal подписку оформлять. У всех сайтов всплывающий алерт с вопросом можно отправлять вам уведомление. да - нет и все.

Comment: Если бы ещё RSS поддерживали, было бы хорошо, было бы вообще класс!

Comment: `Но я так и не понял, как именно на onesignal подписку оформлять.` - как как, регистрируешься там. Заводишь ссылку на свой сайт в настройках, получаешь API key, используешь запросы API